# Drag/Drop File from/in webview

Tags: cocoa

I am making an application featured like mac mail
as in mac mail if we drop a file in message area then that file is as an attached file
and we can drag that file to desktop and double click on the file to open it.
I am using webview(I think webview is used in mac mail)

Can anybody suggest me how can I do this

Thanks
Amit Battan

Comment: Is mac mail using webview?
or anything else

Comment: Yes, Mail uses a `WebView` for composing messages, and displaying the contents of received messages

Answer (score 1):

Subclass the NSWebView and implement NSDraggingDestination.  I recommend you read thru the "Drag and Drop Programming Topics for Cocoa" section of the documentation to learn more about how to properly register for the NSPasteboard types you want.  (NSFilenamesPboardType for OS X before 10.6)

Comment: Do you have a demonstration app or code we can take a look at it?