# Which control is used as editor in mac mail - message body?

Tags: cocoa, webview, textview, rich-text-editor, apple-mail

What is the control used as editor to compose messages in mac mail?

My guess is TextView but I cannot get:

1. How will I show icon in message body when some document is dragged and dropped in it, as in mac mail. Right now it only shows path of document!
2. How will I show vertical bars to represent different quote levels??

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220299/drag-drop-file-from-in-webview) I got the clue that they can have used WebView in mac mail, but this post is still has not been answered.

Can anyone suggest some idea or link or code through which I can implement - formatting messages like in mac mail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple Mail definitely uses a WebView as its editing interface. You'll need to implement the various WebView delegates in order to achieve the functionality you want, there's definitely nothing that will work "out of the box".

Comment: Also, I want to know that -can we get same look and feel like mac mail editor using NSTextView and NSLayoutManager, I mean the quote levels etc??

Comment: I might be off the track. But the context is related to mac mail. Hence, thought of  asking the question here. I have also raised a Question here "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39807402/webview-adding-and-editing-text-as-a-link-objective-c", but did not get a solution. Could someone help me out. Please let me know if you don't get anything.